# App and server backend -> versioning necessary?

Tags: mobile, server, client, versioning

I have built a mobile app for Android and iOS (hybrid app). Now I'm asking myself what's a good practice for managing version conflicts between client (app) and server.

If I change certain api methods on the server side, of course I have to change the client accordingly. But since users of mobile os aren't necessarily forced to update to the latest version, they likely use outdated versions of the app (at least temporarily).

I can think of 2 options to solve that problem:

1. Force app users to update if a new version of the app and the backend is available. This is very low effort for me as developer and a little disadvantage for the user in my opinion.
2. Do a versioning for the server backend (the api) so that every version of the app can access the appropriate version of the api. This is high effort for me.

How do you handle this issue? Am I getting something wrong? Is there a bad practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one :-(? Is the issue that hard?

Comment: Would interesting to learn how you tackled the problem finally;)

Comment: In fact I implemented option 2. But while developing I tried to keep the API as constant as possible.